# Can we use distribution lists inside sharepoint 2016 "Person and Group" column type

Tags: development, active-directory, groups, spuser, person

I have created a new site column of type "Person and group" inside my team site collection inside sharepoint 2016. I configure it to retrieve users and groups from active directory, as follow:-

[image]

now i am facing a problem is that inside active directory we have Distribution lists defined, but seems i am unable to assign them inside the "Person or Group" site column. now seems AD mail enabled security groups can be referenced inside "Person or Group" but distribution lists can not be used... so can anyone adivce if this something i can fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distribution lists cannot be used here as they're used to distribute emails to recipient mailboxes but not more. They do not have any security context as the mail-enabled security groups do.

Comment: so i should ask our customers to create security groups (mail enabled or non-mail enabled) or convert the current distribution lists to be AD security groups... so in this way they can benefit from them inside sharepoint... and i think file servers and web applications (any thing outside exchange) will not understand distribution lists also...